# Spring Security interceptor not restricting access as desired

Tags: spring, spring-security, servlet-filters

I am trying to restrict access to some URL's if a user is not logged in, via Spring Security.

**XML config:**

```xml
<security:http>
    <security:intercept-url pattern="/all/**" access="hasRole('USER')" />
    <security:form-login login-page="/login" authentication-failure-url="/login?error" authentication-success-forward-url="/all/home"/>
    <security:logout  logout-url="/logout" /> 
    <security:custom-filter ref="jwtfilter" after="LOGIN_PAGE_FILTER"/> 
    <security:csrf/>
</security:http>
```

I have a filter which checks if "secure" is there in URL, if it is there then I will perform some check and forward it to controller if everything is right, else reject with "403".

**Filter:**

```java
String aheader=httprequest.getHeader("Authorization");
if (!aheader.isEmpty()) {
    if (this.generator.validateToken(aheader)) {
        Authentication authentication = this.generator.getauthenticated(aheader);
        SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(authentication);
        logger.info("security context");
        //proper
        chain.doFilter(httprequest, httpresponse);  
    } else {
        logger.info("token validation error");
        httpresponse.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_FORBIDDEN);
    }   
} else {
    logger.info("header empty");
    httpresponse.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_FORBIDDEN);
}
```

**Problem:**

If I hit `http://localhost:8080/sweb/all/home` URL then everything is fine.
Spring Security redirects me to login page.

Flow: first my custom filter will get activated and as it does not have "secure" it will be through then Spring will intercept the URL and redirect it to login page.

Now if I hit `http://localhost:8080/sweb/all/secure/getname` URL which
contains  "secure" by custom filter will intercept it and respond with
403/success, but it doesn't show me the login page.

Flow: 403 is rightly displayed but if the condition of filter is true then Why Spring is not intercepting the URL (not getting the login page).

What I want is, first Spring should intercept the URL to check if
user is logged in or not and then check my filter.

Comment: *but if the condition of filter is true then Why Spring is not intercepting the URL (not getting the login page).* What do you get as response? Your page or any error?

Comment: Controller class function is invoked!! Config location:https://github.com/smithlfc/foodAppCentral/tree/master/1FoodUnifier/src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/spring

Comment: Because you are sending a 403... Instead you should throw an exception so that the Spring Security exception filter will handle the error and do the redirect.

Comment: @M.Deinum that is fine, but if the check in filter is through then request is served my by controller despite not being logged in.

Comment: @dur yes I get my page.

Comment: @smith Just to be sure: We are talking about the branch with the line `logger.info("security context");`, right? You are getting the message in your log file?

Comment: @dur yes that line gets printed, I just do header validation (jwt) before that.

Comment: @smith: If you set the `Authentication`with `SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(authentication);` you are authenticated and there is no need  to show the login page.

Comment: @dur yes after commenting that I was able to solve the problem, I was trying to authenticate user from token also, is there any way to get spring interceptor to be invoked first and then my filter? Beacuse my function is rest EP which returns string/json , if I pass the token wrong it gives me 403(due to controller). Thanks for your help!!